# Line chart not displaying properly in iOS

Tags: linechart, ios7.1

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
PCLineChartView *chartLine=[[PCLineChartView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-30)];
        [chartLine setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
    chartLine.minValue=0;
    chartLine.maxValue=100;
    [self.view addSubview:chartLine];

    NSError *error;
    NSString *strFileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                                   pathForResource: @"sample_linechart_data" ofType: @"json"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSData *data = [strFileContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        //NSLog(@"js:%@",json);
    NSMutableArray *secondJson=[json valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
        //NSLog(@"sec js:%@",secondJson);
    NSMutableArray *components=[NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *graphInfo in secondJson) {
        PCLineChartViewComponent *component=[[PCLineChartViewComponent alloc]init];
        [component setTitle:graphInfo[@"title"]];
        [component setPoints:graphInfo[@"data"]];
        [component setShouldLabelValues:NO];
        [component setColour:PCColorBlue];
        [components addObject:component];
    }
    [chartLine setComponents:components];
    [chartLine setXLabels:[json valueForKeyPath:@"xLabels"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the implementation of the line chart. Either you have a problem with that. Or your data is not set correctly. Do you have further information? Could you post additional information please?

Answer (score 0):

Display chart it's a little tricky, I had the same problem, to display chart properly I used this code:

```
PCLineChartView *chart1 = [[PCLineChartView alloc] initWithFrame: /* Your frame */];
//For each component
NSMutableArray *xLabels = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i<chart1.points.count; i++) {
        [xLabels addObject:@""]; //If you don't wanna show a specific text, it's very importan that the quantity of xLabels array be the same than points array
}
chart1.xLabels = xLabels;
```